# Are questions about production of music videos on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, support

I was wondering if it is on-topic here to ask about contents of music videos, when the contents isn't necessarily the music, but how the video was made and put together? But specifically for music videos that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think so. This site is for the music. If you had a question about the music video itself, it would fit in [Music Fans SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/), but a question like the one you asked, pertaining the production of the music video, would be on topic on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/)